# Insert em massa para dentro de uma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

Tenho duas proc's que o meu sistema em VB já utiliza. Uma para Insert e outra para Update. Preciso usá-la agora, direto no banco. A tabela de destino possui uma chave composta, da seguinte forma. Um campo chamado ID_OIT_LET e outro campo chamado ID_OIT. O ID_OIT ele é único, nunca se repete. O campo ID_OIT_LET, ele só recebe 1, 2 ou 3. Quando ele recebe os três valores, aí eu tenho 3 vezes o mesmo valor em ID_OIT, assim:

> ID_OIT_LET ID_OIT
>
> ---
>
> 1  ------------------       39510
>
> 1  ------------------        39511
>
> 1  ------------------        39517
>
> 2  ------------------        39517
>
> 3  ------------------        39517

Na tabela origem, eu tenho o ID_OIT e os campos a serem populados, que é um campo data e um varchar. Quanto ao ID_OIT_LET posso fazer o insert três vezes para gerar os valores 1,2 e 3. A minha dúvida é fazer uma espécie loop na tabela origem, para que ela vá pegando o valor e inserindo. E tem mais um problema. caso já exista aquela chave no banco, então deve-se chamar a PROC de Update e não a de Insert. Gostaria de uma ajuda, para me mostrarem qual caminho tomar. Tô meio sem idéia de como fazer. espero ter sido claro.

Fiz esse insert, conforme o colega José Diz me orientou:

```
declare @UDT table (Num int);
INSERT into @UDT values (1), (2), (3);

SELECT T2.Num, T1.ID_OIT, T1.DT_RX, T1.RX_NUM
  from t_cmo_planilha_leitura as T1
       cross join @UDT as T2;

with cteComb as (
SELECT T2.Num, T1.ID_OIT, T1.DT_RX, T1.RX_NUM
  from t_cmo_planilha_leitura as T1
       cross join (values (1), (2), (3)) as T2 (Num)
)
MERGE
  into #t_cmo_oit1980_leitura_temp1 as D
  using cteComb as O
  on D.ID_OIT_LET = O.Num and D.ID_OIT = O.ID_OIT
  when matched then
       UPDATE set DT_RX= O.DT_RX, RX_NUM= O.RX_NUM
  when not matched by target then
       INSERT (ID_OIT_LET, ID_OIT, DT_RX, RX_NUM)
         values (O.Num, O.ID_OIT, O.DT_RX, O.RX_NUM) 
;
```

O que passa é que, se a tabela está vazia, ele insere normalmente(fiz com uma temp para testes), mas se a tabela tem informação, que no caso tem 8068 registros, não acrescenta nada e me dá essa mensagem:

> (3 linha(s) afetadas)
>
> (3027 linha(s) afetadas) Mensagem 8672, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 104
>   The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source
>   row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target
>   table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row
>   matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group
>   the source rows.

Como proceder?

Comment: tá confuso man. de Qualquer forma pra fazer um loop etc. voce pode usar um cursor no sql pra isso, percorrendo um select com as chaves que voce deseja percorrer

Comment: Os procedimentos de inclusão e atualização recebem o quê como parâmetro? // Eles podem aceitar várias linhas ao mesmo tempo ou somente uma linha de cada vez?

Comment: @JoséDiz, então, preciso antes do insert, gerar o ID_OIT dele na tabela OIT, baseado no código do paciente, que está na tab temp que veio da planilha. Com esse ID então, eu insiro na tabela de destino. Todas as informações de filtro/parâmetro estão na tabela temporária que veio da planilha.

Comment: @pnet: Retirei a parte referente ao código #1, citado somente como modelo no tópico https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/d118763b-a81d-4c55-88c0-07f1438283d3/insert-em-massa-para-dentro-de-uma-tabela?forum=520

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução possível (sem me ater a síntaxe)

Em um bloco protegido

```
BEGIN TRY  
    INSERT INTO ....;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    --SE ERRO DE DUPLICADOS ENTAO
    UPDATE ....;
END CATCH;
```